# return bool from Ajax call to MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an AJAX call to an MVC ActionResult in a controller, trying to return a bool.

My ajax call:

```
function CheckForExistingTaxId() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/clients/hasDuplicateTaxId",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ taxId: taxId }),
    });
}
```

My method: ("clients" is default route prefix)

```
[HttpGet, Route("hasDuplicateTaxId")]
    public ActionResult hasDuplicateTaxId(string taxId)
    {
        //if stuff
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        else
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I want to open a modal dialog based on the result of the ajax call:

```
    if (CheckForExistingTaxId())
        DialogOpen();
```

First problem is I'm getting a 404 Not Found for clients/hasDuplicateTaxId. 
Is there a problem with my route or the way I'm calling it?
Secondly, am I able to return a boolean value in this way, evaluating the function CheckForExistingTaxId() with the ajax call before opening the dialog?

Comment: Ajax considers a request succesful if it get's back "any"  data (thus an empty array means it succeeded), to check if your id exists i would return the id if it was found.

then in your ajax success: check if your data has any objects. if it does that means it already existed.

another option is to return an error if the id already exists, and if it doesn't return empty json, that way you can handle the "ok" scenario in success:  and the duplicate scenario in error:


But to answer your 404 question, that sounds to me like you're not hitting your API at all, can you share your route set-up?

Comment: All routes have "clients" as the prefix, not sure why I'm 404'd

Answer (score 5):

Basically if wanting to use Json with `HttpGet`:

```
    [HttpGet, Route("hasDuplicateTaxId")]
        public ActionResult hasDuplicateTaxId(string taxId)
        {
           // if 1 < 2
           return 1 < 2 ? Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) 
                        : Json(new { success = false, ex = "something was invalid" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

ajax:

```
function CheckForExistingTaxId() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/clients/hasDuplicateTaxId",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ taxId: taxId }),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
               // server returns true
            } else {
               // server returns false
               alert(data.ex); // alert error message
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yep pretty much this. you could augment this by returning an error if you have a duplicate but that's a design decision you'll have to make.

Comment: Pretty much. i meant he could use error: instead of checking success and failure in succes: but this works aswell.

Comment: @Puzzle84 Getting 404 Not Found for "http://localhost/clients/hasDuplicateTaxId?{%22taxId%22:%2211-1111111%22}" when passing in a TaxId of "11-1111111" Any suggesions on why I'm not able to hit my controller method?

Comment: @noclist Have you enabled `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` on `RouteConfig.cs` or tried with `Route("hasDuplicateTaxId/{taxId}")` or `[GET("hasDuplicateTaxId/{taxId}")]`?